# RoR + Devise + Carrierwave: Authenticate with password before uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, carrierwave

I'm creating a profile system on my website with Devise to authenticate a user and Carrierwave to upload an image. However, when I use Carrierwave to upload an image on the user's edit page, it uploads to the account regardless if the user enters a password.

How do I get it to require authentication before uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was something wrong with my configuration of my project. Restarting my project from scratch seemed to fix it.

Comment: It's not very good idea just to trash everything and start from the beginning. If you will do this you will never understand how to find mistakes and errors your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `before_filter` on upload controller. Example :

If you are using `user` for resouce name of devise, Here's example `before_filter`

```
class NamesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  ..
  ..
end
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Comment: I got an error saying **undefined method `before_filter' for ImageUploader:Class**.

Comment: where you put `before_filter` ?

Comment: You should put into controller not uploader class. Can you show me full stack of error?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow me:

1. add in your model

   ```
   attr_accessor :avatar_cache
   ```
2. at you form please adding hidden field

   ```
   <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
   ```

In my scenario I have:

1. coloum avatar in model user.rb
2. please change avatar_cache into your column.